# Container Class is not being inherited

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am beginning to learn CSS and Bootstrap 5. I have this code that doesn't display right.

HTML code:

```css
body, html {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  background-image: url('assets/images/expressway.jpg');
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #6cdb84;
  background-blend-mode: darken;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}

#bg {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: rgb(235, 240, 235);
  clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 0, 100% 42%, 21% 100%, 0 100%, 0% 50%);
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>TemplateUnmannedLcs</title>
    <base href="/">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-BmbxuPwQa2lc/FVzBcNJ7UAyJxM6wuqIj61tLrc4wSX0szH/Ev+nYRRuWlolflfl" crossorigin="anonymous">
  </head>
  
  <body>
    <div class="container mt-5">
      <div id="bg">
      MY HEADER SECTION
      </div>
    </div>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-b5kHyXgcpbZJO/tY9Ul7kGkf1S0CWuKcCD38l8YkeH8z8QjE0GmW1gYU5S9FOnJ0" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Why is it that my div that has the id "bg" overshoots the container constraint. Isn't it that it should only go to the center and not overshoot to the end of the page. See the image below.

[image]

The beginning of the div that has the id "bg" starts out at the correct position but the end overshoots the container boundary. How do I fix this?

Comment: try to align it with `margin-left: Xpx; margin-right: Xpx;` you can also use % instead of pixels

Comment: @vladthelad Thank you Sir. you gave me an idea and I was able to make it work.